# How do I run a python script in react native?

Tags: python, react-native, shared-libraries, .so

**I want an on-device solution. No running python on the server and invoking it via API**

I want to run some post-processing logic in react native and would need to run a python script which will be downloaded from a remote location.

I heard that you can probably bundle the python script as a `.so` file and execute it but I don't know how to do that... so if anyone has some code example of how that would work then it's acceptable as well.

Comment: You could try `pyscript`: https://github.com/Py4Js/PyScript-React

Comment: `pyscript` is based on `wasm` and will not work on the react native environment... it is just meant to be used on the web only I think.